# New Gmail copy/paste adds space before and after

Tags: gmail

It's been a few days now and nothing has changed, but here's the problem:

- Compose a new mail
- Write a few words, let's do this for the explanation: "`---------------`"
- Go straight in the middle, select one character
- Cut it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> (very *classical* way)
- Now paste it with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> (very *classical* way)

And here's the result:

[image: select one char]

[image: after copy then paste the char]

And this behavior is the same in general: you cut + want to paste, Gmail adds space after, and sometimes (yes, *sometimes* not all the time!) before too.

How do I get it to stop doing that?

Comment: At the guy who asked to close it because "This question does not appear to be about computer software or computer hardware within the scope defined in the help center.". Please tell me why it's not about computer software? Aren't we in the `superuser` world? What am I missing?

Comment: Also, does it also happen if you use CTRL-X to cut and CTRL-V to paste? That's a different way to copy/paste, and is often also interpret differently in different systems. For example, if you paste in Powershell using CTRL-V, it also executes that row. But if you Shift-insert, it does paste, but not execute.

Comment: @LPChip It's not a question to ask because all programs: Notepad++, Notepad, PyCharm, PhpStorm, Word, Visual Studio, and the list could go on and on, do behave like this. This is almost a *de-facto* standard. Moreover gmail has always had this "*de-facto* standard" for years. That's why I hate the guy responsible for this because I'm loosing a lot of time copy then paste into notepad and re-cut again to be able to paste.

Comment: @LPChip Ok this is 2s, you'll say? Multiply this by 10 = 20, per 8 hours a day = 2 minutes, per 200 = 400 minutes = 50 hours. I'm loosing 6 days of my life/year because of a brainless guy. And I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one (same problem for forbidden openings of `zip` files and `7z` files in gmail, who is this f**kin guy responsible of this? But this is another story)

Comment: Please lose your anger and come back. We're here to help, not to be there to vent anger on.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it in Chrome (Win), pasted "as-is", without any spaces added

Comment: @OlivierPons Are you saying this happens in other programs too (Notepad++, PyCharm, etc.) or just Gmail?

Comment: @freginold I'm saying it does *not* happen (when you *copy*, insert spaces before and/or after WTF) on all other programs.
@Kos Did you try `CTRL-X` -> `CTRL-V` **or** `SHIFT-DEL` -> `SHIFT-INS`?

Comment: @OlivierPons What browser/system are you using? I just tried it in Gmail in Chrome on a Win7 PC, and it didn't add any spaces.

Comment: Same in Firefox -- no added spaces.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this problem in both Gmail and Google Calendar, in both Chrome and Firefox private windows, using all combinations of `Ctrl+C`, `Ctrl+Insert`, `Ctrl+X`, `Shift+Delete`, `Ctrl+V`, and `Shift+Insert`. The only requirement is the text be pasted into one of Google's HTML-enabled text elements. If I paste into a Gmail draft with "Plain text mode" enabled, for example, no spaces are added. Nor are spaces added if I paste as plain text (`Ctrl+Shift+V`).

Comment: @thinkterry Thank god I'm not the only one! **`:)`**

Comment: It started last week or so for me, it's driving me *nuts*. Chrome/Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for even asking this here. That was sooo annoying and glad it's fixed now.

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron It's not fixed. Write a word. Press enter. Write another word, select it, change the font. Now select the first word, and copy/paste it into a new, empty line. You'll see another **unwanted** space. It's 50% fixed. Maybe the same unskilled person hired by google, who created that mess, did the fix...

Comment: @OliverPons I meant, fixed in the sense that trying Jim Luschen's solution worked, although I have to give up html. I agree that this is a TERRIBLE 'feature' to automatically add spaces on paste like that.

Comment: Reproducible on Chrome 77.0.3865.120 (Win7x64), this has been there as long as I remember. Unfortunately, no way to report bugs to Google, only feedback and we don't know whether they read it or not (most probably not). Or "communities" but they are not present, it's just a place to find work-arounds or vent.

Comment: This problem has been SUPER annoying to me too! And I don't know when it started happening for me, but my sense is that for *me* it has only been happening for months rather than 2 years. It's really disheartening to learn that *2 years* have passed already without this bug being fixed.

Comment: Three years now... **`:)`**

Answer (score 6):

I found the switch to shut this off.

Next to the garbage can icon at the bottom of the Gmail editor window is a down-arrow that brings up a list of options.  One of these options is:

> Plain text mode

If this mode is unchecked (not active) then you get all the annoying spaces inserted when you paste text.  By checking this option, the behavior returns to normal editing conventions.

I have no idea why this option exists.

Comment: When you check this option, it removes all the "HTML" things you've put into your mail: images and text formatting. Even though the copy/paste works, this is not a viable option IMHO...

Comment: You are right.  Plain text mode removes the objectionable behavior you originally described, but at the cost of killing any text editing beyond ACSII content.  It is clear that Google messed up with their Gmail editor.

It's really annoying, isn't it?  Too bad there's no way to let them know.

Comment: It's even worse. Copy/paste now also messes up the formatting, but you cannot see that from within GMail. Your recipients however will see a very unprofessional mix of fonts and sizes, which is absolutely infuriating and inexcusable. Or is it just me?

Comment: @Julian It's not just you, same problem here

Comment: What if one does not need "plain text mode" but needs to disable inserting an extra spaces? Looking for a solution.

Comment: UPD. Still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 6):

If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> it will paste as plain text only, which doesn't add any spaces.

Comment: That works for me. Unbelievable! Thank you so much, I could never have found that on my own.

Answer (score 5):

Not only the spaces are a problem, but also the messed up formatting, as @Julian mentions in a comment.

Many users should [send feedback to Gmail](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/V_U7zBUZ8G4) so that they decide to fix it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/104010)

Comment: This is a Gmail bug. The question is "How do I get it to stop doing that?". The way to achieve that is to ask the Gmail team to fix the bug.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me (getting rid of the auto space and also keeping my hyperlinks) was sending the email to myself first and copying the text from the sent email. For some reason when I copied the text from my draft I got the autospace, but when I copied it from my sent email I didn't.

I was sending 200+ generic emails, so this little trick really helped...